# Text analytics returns 404 'Resource not found'

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Tried to narrow down the problem with Postman. I tried subscriptions in SouthCentralUS and also BrazilSouth, but it's always the same.

POST https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0

Header:
     Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxx
     Content-Type: application/json

Body
     {"url":"https://www.ciclosoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ciclo-software.png"}

Actually I get the same result if I just put the url into the browser as a GET without headers and body. But i don't see what I'm possibly doing wrong. I even thought it could be a internal problem of Azure... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

There are 4 methods in `Text Analytics API` family:

- `Detect language`, for language detection. Endpoint is https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages
- `Entities`: the API returns a list of recognized entities in a given document. Endpoint is https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/entities
- `Key Phrases`: The API returns a list of strings denoting the key talking points in the input text. Endpoint is https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases
- `Sentiment`: The API returns a numeric score between 0 and 1. Endpoint is https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment

[image: South Central US Text Analytics]

As you can see, none of these endpoints match the one you are trying, hence the 404 you got. Moreover, they are all waiting for Text input in a JSON, not a link like you are trying to provide.

Are you looking for an OCR capability? In that case, you should have a look to `Computer Vision API`, and then you have 2 possibilities:

- `OCR` method, see [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)
- `Recognize Text` method, see [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200), currently in preview and only for English text

Comment: Hi! Yes in the meantime I realized that there was a confusion between the service I created and the API I used. I wanted to analyse texts in a picture. With the VisionAPI I could do it, but of course it needs the correct Azure service ;-)

Comment: The message is quite clear... it's an API and it's the web! So if you call an endpoint that does not exist, you got a 404, microsoft or not Microsoft ;-)